# Java Swing - Components Not Visible Unless in Constructor?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm making a Brick Breaker type game in Java using Swing, but none of my Jcomponents are visible unless they are created in the constructor. Another weird note is my current components are only visible if I run `setVisible()` immediately after adding it to the panel. How can I be able to add them later via methods (e.g. within `startGame()`)?

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BrickBreaker gameInstance = new BrickBreaker();
                gameInstance.startGame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**BrickBreaker.java**

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BrickBreaker {

    boolean gameOver = false;
    int frameBoundX = 500;
    int frameBoundY = 600;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    Ball ball;
    Slider slider;
    ArrayList<Brick> brickList = new ArrayList<Brick>();

    public BrickBreaker() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(frameBoundX, frameBoundY);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Add new panel
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        // Add slider
        slider = new Slider(200, frameBoundY - 100, 100, 30);
        panel.add(slider);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add ball
        ball = new Ball(this, frameBoundX, frameBoundY);
        panel.add(ball);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add Bricks
        generateBricks();
        for (Brick brick : brickList) {
            panel.add(brick);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        // Add background
        URL backgroundUrl = BrickBreaker.class.getResource("background.jpg");
        ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(backgroundUrl);
        JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
        backgroundLabel.setBounds(0, 0, backgroundIcon.getIconWidth(),
                backgroundIcon.getIconHeight());
        panel.add(backgroundLabel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startGame() {
        // Add ball
        // ball = new Ball(this, frameBoundX, frameBoundY);
        // panel.add(ball);
        // setVisible(true);
        // panel.repaint();
        // panel.revalidate();

        slider.start();
        ball.start();
    }

    public void endGame() {
        System.out.println("GAME OVER");
        // JLabel endSign = new JLabel("MY TEXT HERE");
        // endSign.setText("GAME OVER");
        // endSign.setBounds(frameBoundX/2, frameBoundY/2, 200, 200);
        // endSign.setForeground(Color.white);
        // endSign.setVisible(true);
        // panel.add(endSign);
        // panel.setVisible(true);
        // // Repaint the panel
        // panel.revalidate();
        // panel.repaint();
        slider.end();
    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return gameOver;
    }

    public void generateBricks() {
        // Unique starting and iterating numbers are due to the window size
        // while also spacing out the bricks evenly
        for (int row = 10; row <= 85; row += 35) {
            for (int b = 5; b < frameBoundX; b += 99) {
                System.out.println("Generating brick #" + b);
                Brick brick = new Brick(b, row);
                brickList.add(brick);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Brick.java** (to see how components are implemented)

```java
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Brick extends JComponent {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width = 94;
    private int height = 30;
    private int health = 1;

    public Brick(int startingX, int startingY) {
        this.x = startingX;
        this.y = startingY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.dispose();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public int reduceHealth(){
        this.health--;
        if (this.health < 1){
            System.out.println("Brick has zero health! Disappearing!");
            setVisible(false);
        }
        return this.health;
    }

}
```

If I try to declare the Slider, Ball, or Bricks anywhere else outside of the constructor they won't appear on screen. Originally, I also had the Main java file utilizing EDT by calling `invokeLater()` but I removed that thinking that might've been an issue, but it's still happening.

Comment: Your code is breaking Swing threading rules. Start everything on the EDT, the event dispatch thread, and use a Swing Timer as your game loop, instead of the `while (true)` and the dreaded `Thread.sleep(...)`, and this should fix a lot of your problems.

Comment: Also, read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) as well as the [Swing Timer Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: _Declaration_ is when you define a _data-type_ and _variable name_,  the assignment is optional.  What you're referring to is just _"assignment"_ or I guess more accurately, the _"initial assignment"_.  And, you're saying if you assign the values outside of the _constructor method_, they don't appear on the screen, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @user85421 - See my updated version of Main.java. That is what I had it looking like but the problem still exists. In my `startGame()` method in BrickBreaker.java I tried using `validate()` and even `revalidate()` plus `repaint()` but nothing worked.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Same comment that I mentioned above. Take a look at my updated copy of Main.java and let me know if I'm still doing something wrong. It's what I had previously at one point. I also added a proper Swing Timer to determine when to end the game, so thank you! Ball is still invisible unfortunately (not that a timer would likely fix it)

Comment: You're violating the layout manager constraints; `panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` but then trying to provide your own bounds, this is just going to end up in a mess.  Personally, I think trying to use components this way is a bad idea and instead, you'd be better of following a pure custom painting route

Comment: I would "suggest" that the `Ball` is invisible for at least two reasons, one, it probably doesn't define a preferred size, so it's default size will be `0x0` and two, the `BorderLayout` will only manage the last component added it it - again, this approach is all wrong

Comment: Stop calling `setBounds` and overriding `getBounds`, you're fighting the layout management system - again, component's are complicated, I think your current approach to using them in this way is wrong. Your `Brick` implementation is, again, all over the place and is making incorrect assumptions about how the component origins and painting works

Comment: @Reilas - Sorry for the confusion, but yes. My components (the Slider, Ball, and Bricks) are declared at the top within the BrickBreaker class but are currently being assigned within the constructor. If I try to assign them elsewhere outside of the constructor they no longer appear in-game. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Don't use `g.dispose()`. You didn't create the Graphics object so you don't need to dispose it.

Answer (score -1):

> *"...  none of my Jcomponents are visible unless they are created in the constructor. ... are only visible if I run `setVisible()` immediately after adding it to the panel. How can I be able to add them later via methods (e.g. within `startGame()`)? ..."*

Modularize the data.
Create a *method* or *class*, for each task.

I recommend encapsulating the *GUI* related data.
Additionally, since *Ball* is accessing *this*, *frameBoundX*, and *frameBoundY*, just *nest* it within that class.

Here is an example.

```java
class BrickBreaker {

    GUI gui;
    boolean gameOver = false;

    static class GUI extends JFrame {
        int frameBoundX, frameBoundY;
        JPanel panel;
        Ball ball;
        Slider slider;
        ArrayList<Brick> brickList;

        GUI() {
            initialize();
            // Add new panel
            add(panel);
            // Add slider
            panel.add(slider);
            // Add ball
            panel.add(ball);
            // Add Bricks
            for (Brick b : brickList) panel.add(b);
            // Add background
            URL backgroundUrl = BrickBreaker.class.getResource("background.jpg");
            ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(backgroundUrl);
            JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
            backgroundLabel.setBounds(0, 0, backgroundIcon.getIconWidth(),
                backgroundIcon.getIconHeight());
            panel.add(backgroundLabel);
            panel.setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(frameBoundX, frameBoundY);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        void initialize() {
            frameBoundX = 500;
            frameBoundY = 600;
            panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            ball = new Ball();
            slider = new Slider(200, frameBoundY - 100, 100, 30);
            generateBricks();
        }

        public void generateBricks() { ... }

        private class Ball extends JComponent {
        }

        private class Slider extends JComponent {
            public Slider(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void startGame() { ... }

    public void endGame() { ... }

    public boolean isGameOver() { ... }
}
```

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    BrickBreaker gameInstance = new BrickBreaker();
    gameInstance.gui = new BrickBreaker.GUI();
    gameInstance.startGame();
    while (!gameInstance.isGameOver()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    gameInstance.endGame();
});
```